# Transactional UNIX shell for file system changes

Tags: shell, filesystems

It is easy to make a mistake when copying (cp), moving/renaming (mv), removing (rm/rmdir), creating dirs (mkdir), and changing file permissions (chmod).  It would be nice to have a log to view before commit.

Is there a tool to do these actions in a "transaction" and allow before/after diff and rollback?  I know my question is very broad as there are a **huge** number of commands that could be supported.  Even if the most basic actions were supported it would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

[Mbox](https://github.com/tsgates/mbox) is a sandbox tool capable of committing the filesystem changes as a whole, and it allows the user to see the diff for each change. It works by using system call interposition.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can look at NILFS - http://nilfs.sourceforge.net/en/

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no tools which supports directly transactions.

But there is for example file systems which supports snapshots like [Btrfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs).

If the file sizes are not very huge, I suggest you to have a look at version-control-systems (VCS) like [git](http://git-scm.com/) which can at least be used to see changes and restore to old versions. For the `/etc`-directory there is for example [`etckeeper`](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/), which also supports file permissions, that are normally not handled totally by VCS systems.